# Race condition Android Studio emulator AVD nearly unusable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit fully patched.  16 GB Ram, I5-4670  CPU @ 3.40 GHZ x 4,  intel graphics, System76 desk top. Android Studio 1.2.1.1 since update to SDK Tools, revision 24.2.

Start the emulator that comes with Android Studio Computer goes into a Race condition.

Then deploy a wizard build project with any combinations of AVD settings Computer goes into a Race condition.

When start and deploy more than 3 emulators computer becomes unusable.

Before update to SDK Tools, revision 24.2 run up to twenty different AVD at the same time with nearly no noticeable effect on the computer.

I filed two bug reports against Android Studio, first one got ignored so I refiled a new one.

Checked on Google, Ask Ubuntu, Stackoverflow. Seems I am the only person that has this problem.

Does any one else have a similar problem? If so can the race problem be fixed?

Comment: What do you mean by 'race condition'?

Comment: Ultra High CPU use, Fan runs wide open

Comment: Check out the screen shoots at:

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=173578&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars